# How to edit this php function?

Tags: php, sql-server

How to edit:
`'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'],`

Because now it display for example: `2013-08-19 18:55:00` but when it's `NULL` i want it to display `N/A`

PS. It's getting data from MSSQL 2005 database (TransferTime row in the table)

Will be much appreciated.

Comment: `'char_transfertime' => ((is_null($data['TransferTime'])) ? 'N/A' : $data['TransferTime']),`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this cannot be exploited right?

Comment: I have similiar query like this: `'char_clan'  => !isset($data['IDName']) ? "N/A" : '<a href="./?page=clan&id=' . $data['Knights'] . '">' . $data['IDName'] . '</a>');` we may use `isset` ?

Comment: It's only exploitable if your existing code is exploitable

Comment: Alright, thanks. And so we cannot use `isset` and `is_null` is the best in that case ?

Comment: You wanted to test for when the value is NULL; so is_null() is the correct function: though isset() would work as well

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Lastly to make sure ... I understand if my rest of the code is exploitable thats common sense but regarding this one you gave me it's totally fine and we cannot use anything different for what i want to make it more secure ?

Comment: Which is better in that case `isset()` or `is_null()` ?

Comment: Whichever you prefer is better.... use isset() or is_null() as you like, and it will make absolutely no difference from a coding perspective

Comment: Both are secure equal is that what I should understand ?

Comment: And neither is more secure than the other: and if there is a security problem with the `TransferTime` column on your data table, neither will make any difference - but unless your database is already compromised, and your `TransferTime` is a text field, and somebody has placed some harmful code in it, and you echo that code - then this will make absolutely no difference. In the extreme circumstance I've outlined above, then none of those functions will help

Comment: Basically that means I shouldn't be afraid of something since both my default one: `'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'],` and your `'char_transfertime' => ((is_null($data['TransferTime'])) ? 'N/A' : $data['TransferTime']),` are same in terms of security since it depends on my rest code. Is that correct ?

Comment: That's right, on the rest of your code and on your database - this change will not in any way affect the security of your application

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot. Please post it as an aswear, so I can click solved.

Comment: Also, my TransferTime is date column since it display date: `2013-08-14 20:22:00` is that okay to use `$data` ?

Comment: If it's a valid MySQL date datatype, and not a string datatype such as varchar or text which is used to store a "human-readable" formatted date; then it's not going to be exploitable when reading and displaying data

Comment: The column in database shows its `smalldatetime` is that totally okay and am I safe ? :)

Comment: smalldatetime datatype is OK, you can't store text in a smalldatetime field

Comment: So, It should be secured this case and I am fine to use what you provided ?

Comment: yes it should be fine: why do I believe there's a corporate lawyer sitting next to you?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's ternary operator with is_null() or isset()

```
'char_transfertime' => ((is_null($data['TransferTime'])) 
    ? 'N/A' 
    : $data['TransferTime']),
```

Comment: The column in database shows its smalldatetime is that totally okay and am I safe ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit the function itself, but you can do a check to see if the result is `null`.

```
'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'];

if(is_null('char_transfertime')){
    'char_transfertime` = 'N/A';
}
```